# Navigation, moving second level of my nav few pixels to the left

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation:

http://jsfiddle.net/XDnD9/

It works fine, but I would like to move the `fdsa` about 10 pixels to the left. If I add `left: -10px;` in there, it will position itself in the left of the screen. If I change position to relative, then it crashes my list. How do I position this sub-list 10px to the left?

**Edit:** Sine I see that it wasn't clear, I want to move `fdsa` **<-** this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following:

```
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

And

```
ul > li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

`position: relative` makes the absolute positioning of nested elements being calculated relatively to that element, so `left: -10px;` no longer moves inner elements next to the left side of the screen.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDnD9/5/)

Comment: Thank you, but your demo moves it to the right, and I want to move it to the left. Sorry for being unclear, updated my post already.

Answer (score 1):

make this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XDnD9/3/)**

```
ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin:0 0 0 15px;

}
```